# Make div fill up rest of the parent

Tags: html, css

I have a header/ container with no specified width (therefore it's as long as the parent). Inside that, I have two smaller divs. Now, the first one should only contain a picture (with a set size), and the other should be as big as there's space left. I can't use a set width, because I don't know the width of the header. 
How do I do this with pure CSS?

What I want ultimately is a picture, then some text aligned to the right top, and then some text aligned with the bottom of the picture on the left. 
Do you know of any better way to do this?

Here's a picture so it's easier to understand:

[image: Example]

Thanks, Aleksander

**EDIT 1:**

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="header_left">
    <div class="pic"><img width="35px" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Volkswagen_Logo.png" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="header_right">
    <div class="time">18m ago</div>
    <div class="name">Volkswagen</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
}

.header_left {
  display: inline-block;
}   
  .pic {
    margin: 5px;
  }

.header_right {
  display: inline-block;
}
  .time {
    margin: 5px;
    float: right;
  }
  .name {
    margin: 5px;
    float:left;
  }
```

It's kinda' messy right now, because what I've just been trying a lot of stuff, and this is the last thing.

Comment: It would be a lot more easier with your code. Post it, so we can see what you tried and tell you where the problem is

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I've now added some code (though it might not help a lot, because I just want to know a way to do this. My code is probably rubbish :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier if you displayed your html. Here's an example based on your description. You can see this working in the fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/Z68ds/18/

```
.header {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding: 4px;
    background: #ddd;
}

.caption {
    float: right;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.avatar {
    float: left;
}

.title {
    margin: 14px 0 0 38px;
}

<div class="header">
    <div class="caption">
        texty text2
    </div>
    <img class="avatar" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dv0i.jpg?s=32&g=1" />
    <div class="title">texty text1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to be able to reference texty text1 later (through use of ID), and therefore it need to be in an div (or paragraph or something else). But when I use a div, without any extra markup, it's pushed down below the picture. How do I solve that?

Comment: I've updated the markup. If you know the height and width of the image then this should work.
If you have varying heights of the image/width the layout will be come a little more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `overflow` in the element you don't want to set a width **without floating it**.

```
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}

#right {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will force the `#right` element to cover the rest of its parent. No extra markup needed.

[image: jsFiddle]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to achive?

```
<div id="header">
  <img id="logo" src="http://blog.grio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png" />
  <p id="textRight">texty text2</p>
  <p id="textLeft">texty text1</p>
  <div class="clearer"></div>
</div>

/* CSS */

#logo {
    float: left;
}
#textRight {
    float: right;
}
#textLeft {
    clear: right;
    float: left;
}
.clearer {
    clear: both;
}
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/T26cD/

Comment: It nearly works, but the problem is that "texty text1" isn't aligned with the bottom of the picture, when the picture is only 35px high and the font is quite big... Any way to solve this without changing pic-size or font-size?
See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T26cD/1/